# How can I assign a TypeScript type for event payloads for a class like EventEmitter?

Tags: typescript, eventemitter

I have a class that is just like Node's EventEmitter (it could even be the same class).

How do I type it in such a way that I can specify what the callback type is for each different event name?

For example, I'd like for even `"foo"` to have a payload of type `number`, and event `"bar"` to have a payload of type `string`, as in:

```
const emitter = /* get emitter from somewhere. And how would the type definition look like? */

emitter.on('foo', payload => {
  /* type of payload is number, enforced by TypeScript */
  testNumber('foo') // TS error, 'foo' is not a number
  testNumber(payload) // it works, payload is a number
})

emitter.on('bar', payload => {
  /* type of payload is string, enforced by TypeScript */
  testString(5) // TS error, 5 is not a string
  testString(payload) // it works, payload is a string
})

function testNumber( value: number ) {}
function testString( value: string ) {}
```

How would we define the EventEmitter declaration so that it is possible to define events and their types, and to then let users use those events with the correct type checking?

Maybe there's a way to define the type of EventEmitter such that when I create one I pass a type argument that contains all the expected types?

Is there a way to do it dynamically after creation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd start off with something like this:

```
interface Events {
  foo: number
  bar: string
}

interface EventEmitter<T> {
  on<K extends keyof T>(s: K, listener: (v: T[K]) => void): T[K];
}

declare const emitter: EventEmitter<Events>;

emitter.on('foo', (payload: any) => {
  testNumber(payload)
  testString(payload)
});

emitter.on('bar', (payload: any) => {
  testNumber(payload)
  testString(payload)
});

function testNumber( value: number ) {}
function testString( value: string ) {}
```

Here's an [example on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcLgM7IN4CwAUMsjAPbkBcyIArgLYBG0xpTcUN2YUoA5sQC+xYqEixEKDFjCoGwMBIA8AFWQQAHpBAATXOSYArCAjAA+fG2TkQygNIbtWfcgDWEAJ7kYyVeYAKbBp7ABpkABtgHixoGgD0GlUAbXsAXQBKZABeS3RyYF0MpNS0gG5hUSJdUwjOFARbHg0FJTi0THB5RRUZHHMKomIIVokAOlsAgHIKcinwgIAHOE8I8jhdGjgQTyzcqxJkSB4AOUYWKCWVtY2M62OwAGVeASvV9aLhDMHh0egJkDTDhQebIN43TbIba7HKWQiHB5nZjQcEfO4IiA8Z58ED8VG3L4-IgwOggMzAWxHTFgJEXALIdBwCJ0CA0ejIqDILJ4ZCNEDYcgRCBjNZ4xnMiDfZAiYmk8mUh7Y14Mpks7gvXFc-C8pqC4WihKqyVlaXEIA).

Comment: Awesome! The mapped types are hard to grok, but this is helping me get there. Thanks!

Comment: @trusktr Glad I could help.

Comment: What if the emitter instance is imported from a module, and I'd like to add a new event and payload type to it? Basically I don't have access to a predefined set of `Events`, and can only import the `emitter` instance. Is it possible?

Comment: What does `K extends keyof T` mean exactly?

Comment: @trusktr Have a read of https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Oh! Can I type cast the instance to a new type using a union? F.e. `import emitter from 'somewhere'; const newEmitter = emitter as EventEmitter<Event & MyEvents>` ? Is there another way you'd recommend augmenting the event types if I only have the `emitter` instance?

Comment: @trusktr It's probably best to ask a separate question on here.